# Which file does Chrome save cookies in?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, browser, path, chromium

I am trying to create a script for adding or removing cookies in Chrome before opening the browser.
I know that cookies are stored somewhere in the patch:
"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"

but there are thousands of files inside User Data...

Does anyone know the name and direct path where cookies are stored?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question:

C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
You'll need a program like SQLite Database Browser to read it.

For Mac OS X, the file is located at :-
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies

Comment: This is no longer correct. Cannot find Chrome cookies anywhere...